# Stickyjs and jumping navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

How to fix a sticky navigation bar on a site?

The problem is that the header section just jumps to the left at the moment, when I start scrolling, I just want it to stay exactly where it is, if I add `position:absolute;` to the section it stops to jump, great, however, the site has a blue line, that has the navigation menu on and goes across the width of the page, this is regardless of how wide the screen is.

If I use the `position:absolute;` code on the header section it stops the line from appearing across the remaining space and cuts it in line with the actual body of the website. The footer remains fine and its making it look unbalanced.
Can anyone think of a way to not lose the blue strip?

Also, for some reason part of the header section, which covers the shopping cart and items inside doesn't want to move down with the sticky header, it gets left behind at the top. Is there an easy way in coding to just associate whatever that section is to be part of the `header section`, or will I have to create a second sticky code for that and make it float in the correct place?

What can I give to help out any further, I'm using the stickyjs plugin, although if you can figure a way to fix everything using another method it will be great.

This link shows what the site is doing at my current stage:
http://pressparts.oxatis.com/Default.asp?ADContext=1

Comment: provide html and css code, that relates to the problem, also jsfiddle will be great.

Answer (score 0):

For a sticky navigation bar on a website you should use

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

This will put your nav bar on the top-left corner of the screen, regardless of scrolling.

Comment: This just breaks the design, i'm guessing the way the designer built it didn't put anything into account for the header section to disappear and it shifts everything up, I guess it would work but it would  require much more messing around with the CSS to get it working, as i'm more or less completely retarded when it comes to coding right now i'm finding it hard to figure it all out. I did add an example after you had posted, might have given more of an idea